# Why do Jaegers have swords?

Tags: pacific-rim, mecha

In the movie they prove that the swords aren't really necessary with the rocket punches and all.

[image: The actual rocket punch]

Their resilience and strength is superior to a lot of kajjus. Instead of using a sword to cut couldn't the Jaeger just rip the body part off? Would any of the weapons like the laser cannon or missiles be more effective than the sword? I understand that most things in this movie happen for the sake of the moment where the mountain dew drinking sw@g master says "whoa that's so rad" but there are other ways to pierce or slice than with a sword, like with I don't know plasma? or Lazers? you could literally just make a constant beam of that gun and slice the kajju in half!

Comment: Because rip and tear. Oh, and they're one-hit kills for some reason, while rocket-assisted punches are shrugged off

Comment: Didn't see the movie, but have seen where people are asking why they didn't use the swords *more*!

Comment: That rocket punch is only going about 60-100 MPH. Were it going 3,000 MPH, I could see where it'd do better than a sword.

Comment: Because swords are cool. Did you miss the part where every single thing in this film happens because of that?

Comment: so if a rocket punch goes 60-100 mph what would the difference be with a sword going 60-100 mph hitting a kajju's hard shell?

Comment: @Fox-Chan A sword is much more efficient at delivering power to a smaller location, increasing damage. Furthermore, the tip of the sword moves faster than the arm swinging it, granting even more ability to do damage.  It's why we have swords.

Comment: that brings me to another point, why even engage them at close range? why not just make a sniper rifle like thing?

Comment: Rocket propelled swords?

Comment: Rocket sword-chucks?

Comment: Last-ditch. Rockets and plasmar and lasers cost a lot of energy to use. Once that energy is depleted, then you must resort to a more rudimentary weapon. Even a soldier IRL will pull out his knife once he's out of ammo (and in close quarters). Remember, the sword wasn't their first weapon of choice.

Comment: "In the movie they prove that the swords aren't really necessary with the rocket punches and all." Did you miss the part where rocket punches weren't enough, but the sword was?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not only would a sword provide **additional reach** to dismember a kaiju, but it is also **more effective**.

To rip a body part off would require both hands of the jaeger to be on the kaiju for the length of time to remove said limb, which would probably just end up getting the jaeger damaged.  While trying to tear off a kaiju limb, the kaiju would be fighting back to prevent the loss of the limb using any means necessary.  A sword would be a quicker, less dangerous way to remove a body part.

As for why don't they have a constant beam gun to slice a kaiju in half, that sounds like a lightsaber with a gun for a hilt ;)  If you are thinking the beam extends for longer than a typical lightsaber, how much energy is that using and how long would the energy last?  If you are fighting alongside other jaegers would a weapon that long be helpful or a hindrance?

Comment: but that would be the point you wouldnt need to use any other Jaegers you could just send one with a lightsaber like thing

Comment: or why not just snipe the damn thing? like I honestly dont see why they have  to engage at such close quarters

Comment: The kaiju were getting bigger and bigger in the movie to better fight the jaeger.  If you just have one with the beam gun thing, they might adapt by getting smaller and just dodging/overwhelming your one jaeger.

Comment: Also see @Richard's comment for why use swords/close combat :)

Comment: Snipe... with what?  Fast moving target miles away with a shell that could both penetrate and do enough internal damage... I think you'd need a railgun the size of the city you're trying to defend.  Which by the way, would be a wonderful sitting duck target.

Comment: @Fox-Chan because no movie?